# Creating a BST from an array

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, parent-child, binary-search-tree, subtree

I need to create a binary search tree in the following (strange) way:

I am given an array (A[n]). A[1] becomes the root of the tree.

- Then, I insert A[1]+A[2] to the left subtree (subtree1, used below) of the root and also insert A[1]-A[2] to the right subtree (subtree2) of the root.
- I insert A[1]+A[2]+A[3] to the left subtree of subtree1 (subtree3) and A[1]+A[2]-A[3] to the right subtree of subtree1 (subtree4).
- Then, I insert A[1]-A[2]+A[3] to the left subtree of subtree2 (subtree5) and A[1]-A[2]-A[3] to the right subtree of subtree2 (subtree6).
- I repeat for subtree3, subtree4, subtree5, subtree6 until I reach the end of the array.

So, basically, the first element of the array becomes the root of the tree and then I move down: Every left subtree has for value the sum of its parent plus the next element of the array and every right subtree has for value the difference of its parent and of the next element in the array.

I understand I need to use the concept of recursion but in a modified way. Typing my problem here and trying to explain it to someone else apart from my brain actually made me form it in a way that gave me some ideas to try but I can see the problem I am dealing with being a usual problem so maybe you could give me some pointers on how to use recursion to build the tree.

*Looking around at other questions and the discussions I understand there is a policy against asking whole solutions so I wanted to make it clear that I am not asking for the solution but for guidance to it. If someone would like to have a look I can show you what I've already done.*

Answer (score 0):

The way to do recursion is to always assume you already have a working function in hand. So let's see [using Java syntax]...

```
Tree buildTree(int currentSum, int[] array, int index, boolean sign);
```

Suppose that works. Then would do u need to do to build a tree at index i?

```
// current value to look at at this level
int curValue = array[index];
// depending on sign, it may be negative
if (!sign) { 
  curValue *= -1;
}
// add it to the running total
int nodeValue = currentSum + curValue;
Node nd = new Node(nodeValue);

nd.left = buildTree(nodeValue, array, index + 1, true);
nd.right = buildTree(nodeValue, array, index + 1, false);
```

That's basically it. You need to take care of the edge cases: of index = array.length, creation of the very first node, and the like